# Spring - Return string result of endpoint and storing it on a variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is my endpoint and it returns me my email address when logged in

```
@GetMapping("/user")
public String userInfo(Authentication authentication) {
    String userName = authentication.getName();
    return userName;
}
```

I want to give the `createdBy` variable this value

```
@PostMapping("/request")
public RequestDTO saveRequest(@RequestBody final RequestDTO requestDTO) {
    requestDTO.setCreatedBy(InsertTheNewStringVariableHere);
    return requestUseCase.createRequest(requestDTO);
}
```

Comment: If your classes are int he same project, you can call it directly. If not the case, you can use a `rest client` to call your API.

Comment: @HarryCoder how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have authentication in both endpoints you can simply add `Authentication` as a parameter in the second endpoint:

```java
@PostMapping("/request")
public RequestDTO saveRequest(@RequestBody final RequestDTO requestDTO, 
                              Authentication authentication) {
    requestDTO.setCreatedBy(authentication.getName());
    return requestUseCase.createRequest(requestDTO);
}
```

Comment: Just tried and it gives me null. 
I don't get why it will return me the username *only* if I use that endpoint
Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Do you call the `/user` endpoint with any credentials or any other form of authentication?

Comment: I just call it on my browser and it returns the current logged in user

Comment: Yes but do you provide any form of authentication? I guess that you must, otherwise it makes no sense that `userInfo(Authentication authentication)` is able to inject the `Authentication` object but `saveRequest(@RequestBody final RequestDTO requestDTO, Authentication authentication)` can't.

Comment: Believe it not, that's what happens

Comment: Can you add your security configuration to the question? Additionally, are both entpoints part of the same Controller? If so can you please include the whole class? Thanks!

Comment: This is the endpoint: https://textuploader.com/t59xm
This is spring security: https://textuploader.com/t59xx
If I need to add anything, please tell me

Comment: Then you are actually requiring credentials on every single call to your API. Having said that, when calling `@PostMapping("/request")` you should also be providing username and password or any other type of "credential" (I would bet on a JSESSIONID). If you do that then you will be able to get a non-null `Authentication` in your `saveRequest()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Its all depend on how your access your `rest api`.

If you own the code, I mean if your classes are in the same project, you can do this:

```
@PostMapping("/request")
public RequestDTO saveRequest(@RequestBody final RequestDTO requestDTO) {
    requestDTO.setCreatedBy(yourServiceInstance.userInfo(authentication));
    return requestUseCase.createRequest(requestDTO);
}
```

If it is an external `api`, you will have to call the service from a `http client`:

```
@PostMapping("/request")
public RequestDTO saveRequest(@RequestBody final RequestDTO requestDTO) {
    requestDTO.setCreatedBy(yourHttpClient.callUserInfo(authentication));
    return requestUseCase.createRequest(requestDTO);
}
```

You will inject your `userInfo` object and a `Authentication` object in your class.

Comment: Can you give me an example of "yourServiceInstance"?

Comment: What is the name of the class of your method `userInfo` ?

Comment: https://textuploader.com/t59tt
Im sending this just to be sure

Comment: `yourServiceInstance` will be an instance of `RequestController`  and you will inject it in the contructor of the class that own your method `saveRequest`

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using `SecurityContextHolder`

```
    @PostMapping("/request")
     public RequestDTO saveRequest(@RequestBody final RequestDTO requestDTO) {
         Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
         requestDTO.setCreatedBy(authentication.getName());
         return requestUseCase.createRequest(requestDTO);
     }
```